# How to update constraints of a view when other view is hidden using Snapkit?

Tags: ios, swift3, snapkit

There are three views from top to bottom: redView, yellowView, blueView.
I want to hide yellowView and change the constraint of blueView in order to let blueView below redView.
The picture is below:
  [this picture is original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRuS9.png)
  [this picture is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owYLN.png)
The code is below:

```
private lazy var redView: UIView = {
   let redView = UIView()
    redView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    return redView
}()
private lazy var yellowView: UIView = {
   let yellowView = UIView()
    yellowView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    return yellowView
}()
private lazy var blueView: UIView = {
   let blueView = UIView()
    blueView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    return blueView
}()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.addSubview(redView)
    view.addSubview(yellowView)
    view.addSubview(blueView)
    redView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.top.left.right.equalTo(view)
        make.height.equalTo(40)
    }
    yellowView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.top.equalTo(redView.snp.bottom)
        make.left.right.height.equalTo(redView)
    }
    blueView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.top.equalTo(yellowView.snp.bottom)
        make.left.right.height.equalTo(yellowView)
    }
```

}

```
    if yellowView.isHidden == true {
        //how is the code?
    } else {
        //how is the code?
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need set height constraint for yellow view and take IBOutlet for its height constraint of yellowView and modify its constant as per hide/show .

```
  if yellowView.isHidden == true {
            //how is the code?
            ibHeightOutletOfYellow.constant = 0; // hide here
        } else {
            //how is the code?
            ibHeightOutletOfYellow.constant = 50; // as per your needed

        }
```